# Reading / Sorting a File using VB.Net

Tags: arrays, vb.net, loops, csv, readfile

I have a project to read and sort a file :

1234562343243489897654,876546322348976549876543,8974323467890965436654
2345675432345678996525,457843984164457832445546,6356455644546653544236
.
.
.
.

I am using VB.Net , i want to read this file, extract some digits from each line according to certain conditions(like, extract last/first 17 digits from each line). i read the file using system.io.file.readalllines. please help me to extract digits and sort .

my code is

```
Dim alllines As String = "/Path"
Dim Lines = File.ReadAllLines(alllines)
Dim newline As String = ""

For Each line In Lines
    newline = line.Substring(0, 17)
    Richtextbox1.Text=Richtextbox1.Text + newline
Next
```

but output shows the substring from the last line only..

Comment: What have you researched or tried so far? Have you got some code to show us please? Is there a specific problem when you attempt to do an extract and/or sort?

Answer (score 0):

this is your code

```
    Dim MyFile As String = PathToFileString
    Dim Lines = File.ReadAllLines(MyFile)
    Dim newLines As ArrayList = New ArrayList()
    Dim newLine As String = ""

    For Each line In Lines
        newLine = line.Substring(line.Length - 17, 17)
        newLines.Add(newLine)
    Next

    newLines.Sort()
```

Comment: Please don't use ArrayList in new code. We have much better typed collections available in .net. In this case List(Of String) would work.

Comment: thank you for your time,but it shows 'index was out of the bounds of the array' my code is                                                                                                       
  Dim i as integer                                                                                             
  Dim allLines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("myFilePath")
Dim lines(allLines.Length - 1) As String
For i = 0 To lines.Length - 1
    lines(i) = allLines(i).Substring(0, 17)
Next
System.Array.Sort(lines)                       Richtextbox1.Text=Richtextbox1.Text+lines(i)

Comment: where s the error? which line? try to use ForEach instead for i = 0

Answer (score 0):

this is your code:

```
Dim allLines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("myFilePath")
Dim lines(allLines.Length - 1) As String
For i = 0 To lines.Length - 1
    lines(i) = allLines(i).Substring(0, 17)
Next
System.Array.Sort(lines)
```

Comment: The OP asked for the last 17 digits not the first 17 digits in the line.

Comment: thank you for your time,but it shows 'index was out of the bounds of the array' my code is                                                                                                       
  Dim i as integer                                                                                             
  Dim allLines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("myFilePath")
Dim lines(allLines.Length - 1) As String
For i = 0 To lines.Length - 1
    lines(i) = allLines(i).Substring(0, 17)
Next
System.Array.Sort(lines)                       Richtextbox1.Text=Richtextbox1.Text+lines(i)